# Command Line with C#

Tags: c#, command-line, autodesk-navisworks

I'm trying to run a software's batch utility tool via C# and the command line but am not able to get it to work.  I am able to build a string which is correct and works when I just copy and paste it into the command prompt, but when my code tries to do that step automatically nothing happens; the script just runs to the end and nothing happens.

For reference, this is what I'm trying to do: https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/navisworks-products/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2020/ENU/Navisworks/files/GUID-14B017E2-B4A2-432F-8C2D-1F1856EECB8E-htm.html

I've tried a number of times changing the different properties of StartInfo, but nothing has worked so far.  Could there be an issue with the different directories that are at play?

- "filesTextFile" is a .txt file on the C: drive which lists paths for files located on a shared network drive (\\{network}\)
- cmd.exe is in the C: drive
- "NWBatchUtilityLoc" variable is the file path for an .exe on the C: drive
- .cs script is running from the D: drive.

This is an excerpt of my code that shows how the string is being built and how I am using `System.Diagnostics.Process`.

```
var utilityCmd = $@"""{NWBatchUtilityLoc}"" /i ""{filesTextFile}"" /osd /log ""{logDir}"" /lang en-US";

var p = new Process
{
     StartInfo =
     {
         FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe",
         Arguments = "/C " + utilityCmd,
     }
};

p.Start();
```

Comment: Use /K instead of /C so you can see any error messages.

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Process can be difficult to work with. You may find it easier to use a library like SimpleExec or CliWrap; at the very least they'll make it a bit easier to get/see the output of the command.

Comment: @HansPassant, when I do that it outputs "'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command."  That makes it seem like its not recognizing all of the `NWBatchUtilityLoc` string because the first part of that string is a file path to the batch utility .exe (C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Navisworks Manage 2021\FiletoolsTaskRunner.exe).

Comment: "Double quotes" around the path required.  The code is weird, looks like it was copied from vb.net code.  In C# it is ` \" ` to embed a double quote.

Comment: @HansPassant, that's good to know, I didn't know that was the way to do double quotes in C#.  That's why I used `@"""`.  It still works the same way and doesn't run any differently though, I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: You are trying to start an exe. Why not use *that* as command, instead of cmd.exe?